# Avalonia Dynamic Tree View MVVM

Tags: treeview, avaloniaui

In Avalonia,
I want to create a file tree view.
When I write

```
      <TreeView Height="500" Background="Red" >
        <TreeViewItem Header="h0">
          <TreeViewItem Header="h11"></TreeViewItem>

        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="h1"></TreeViewItem>

      </TreeView>
```

It works, but obvisously, it's static.

I tried

```
    <TreeView Height="500" Background="Red" Items="{Binding Files}">
      <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <TreeDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
        </TreeDataTemplate>
      </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

with the ViewModel:

```
public class RepoFileViewModel : ReactiveObject, IRoutableViewModel
{
    public string? UrlPathSegment { get; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public IScreen HostScreen { get; }

    public RepoFileViewModel(IScreen screen,)
    {
        HostScreen = screen;
        
        TreeViewItem Root = new TreeViewItem();

        TreeViewItem l1a = new TreeViewItem { Header = "level 1 a" };
        TreeViewItem l1b = new TreeViewItem { Header = "level 1 b" };
        TreeViewItem l1c = new TreeViewItem { Header = "level 1 c" };
        Root.Items = new List<TreeViewItem>
        {
            {l1a },{l1b},{l1c }
        };
        TreeViewItem l2ba = new TreeViewItem { Name = "level 2 b a" };
        l1b.Items = new List<TreeViewItem>
        {
            { l2ba }
        };

        Files = Root;

        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Files");


    }

    private TreeViewItem files;
    public TreeViewItem Files
    {
        get => files;
        set
        {
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref files, value);
        }
    }


}
```

It does not work.

How to properly create a dynamic TreeView using MVVM and XAML in Avalonia?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <TreeView Items="{Binding Items}" >
      <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <TreeDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </TreeDataTemplate>
      </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

```
public RepoFileViewModel(IScreen screen)
{
    HostScreen = screen;


    FileTreeElement root = new FileTreeElement("root");
    FileTreeElement e0 = new FileTreeElement("level 0 a");
    FileTreeElement e1 = new FileTreeElement("level 0 b");
    FileTreeElement e2 = new FileTreeElement("level 0 c");
    FileTreeElement e3 = new FileTreeElement("level 1 a");
    e1.Items.Add(e3);
    root.Items.Add(e0);
    root.Items.Add(e1);
    root.Items.Add(e2);

    this.Items = root.Items;
    this.RaisePropertyChanged("Files");

    
}

private ObservableCollection<FileTreeElement> items;
public ObservableCollection<FileTreeElement> Items
{
    get => items;
    set
    {
        this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref items, value);
    }
}
```

works!